# How can I create a customized environment?

Tags: environments, theorems, ntheorem

I would like to write some theorems down like this:

```
\begin{theorem}
    \begin{preconditions}
        $A := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$\\
        $B := \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$\\
        $n \in \mathbb{N}$
    \end{preconditions}

    \begin{claim}
        $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$
    \end{claim}

    \begin{proof}{directly}
        [... the proof ...]
    \end{proof}

\end{theorem}
```

It should look like this:

```
**Theorem 123**
    **Preconditions**:
        $A := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$\\
        $B := \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$\\
        $n \in \mathbb{N}$

    **Claim**: √2 ∉ Q

    **Proof**: directly

        [... the proof ...]
        [.. the end]                 ■
```

(`Theorem 123`, `Preconditions`, `Claim` and `Proof` should be bold)

**Logic behind the environment:**

- the theorems should automatically get a number that starts by one and counts up by one for each theorem
- inside of the theorem environment, only the `preconditions`, `claim` and `proof` environments are allowed
- inside of the theorem environment, the `claim` and `proof` environment are required to be exactly once.
- the content of proof and the content of preconditions should have the same intendation.

**What I've found so far:**

I thought [\newenvironment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX#New_Environments) might be what I am searching for:

```
\newenvironment{name}[num]{before}{after}
```

but I could not figure out how to mark internal environments as required.

---

The amsthm package seem to have environments for proof ([source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems)), but I can't see a possibility to nest the different environments and make them look like I want them to look

---

[ntheorem](http://www.bitlib.net/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf) seems to offer a lot of possibilities. I have created 4 new theorem environments:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{preconditions}{Preconditions}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
```

I have used the latex code from above and got this:
[image]

This one has no intendation of the inner environments, the inner environments are numbered although they shouldn't be numbered and no [tombstone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_%28typography%29) is at the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package as a front-end for `amsthm` in order to define a new `Proof` environment; the other two environments were created using `\newenvironment`. The `Proof`, `claim` and `precondition` environments use `adjustwidth` from the [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package to increase the left margin. Of course, feel free to make the necessary adjustments according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\newlength\Thmindent
\setlength\Thmindent{20pt}

\newenvironment{precondition}
  {\par\medskip\adjustwidth{\Thmindent}{}\normalfont\textbf{Preconditions:}\par\nobreak}
  {\endadjustwidth}
\newenvironment{claim}
  {\par\medskip\adjustwidth{\Thmindent}{}\normalfont\textbf{Claim:}}
  {\endadjustwidth}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=0pt,spacebelow=0pt,
  preheadhook=\adjustwidth{\Thmindent}{},
  prefoothook=\endadjustwidth,
  headpunct=:,
  numbered=no,
  qed=\qedsymbol
]{proof}
\declaretheorem[style=proof]{Proof}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{precondition}
\begin{itemize}
\item $A := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$
\item $B := \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$
\item $n \in \mathbb{N}$
\end{itemize}
\end{precondition}
\begin{claim}
$\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}$
\end{claim}
\begin{Proof}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Proof}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]